# How can I have a check box control form submit properties?

Tags: forms, email, infopath, infopath2010

I'm putting together a pretty basic InfoPath 2010 form that will be filled out in a browser (by non-logged in users) and will generate an email upon submission. The client that I building the site for would like a user to be able to check a box to mark whether they would like to have the email address that they provided be CC'd on the form submission.

I know how to CC the email upon submission, but I haven't found anything that talks about using a check box to control it. I have tried playing around with rules and submit button options, but couldn't get exactly what I wanted to stick.

What I need is: if a user checks a box, they will get CC'd upon submission, and if they leave the check box unchecked, then they receive no email.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code behind of the InfoPath form to accomplish this. Get the XPath of the field associated with the checkbox in the Form_Submit method of the code behind. If the field returns true, go ahead and CC, otherwise, don't CC.